# inheriting ostream and streambuf problem with xsputn and overflow

Tags: c++, iostream, ostream, streambuf

I have been doing research on creating my own ostream and along with that a streambuf to handle the buffer for my ostream.  I actually have most of it working, I can insert (<<) into my stream and get strings no problem.  I do this by implimenting the virtual function xsputn.  However if I input (<<) a float or an int to the stream instead of a string xsputn never gets called.

I have walked through the code and I see that the stream is calling do_put, then f_put which eventually tries to put the float 1 character at a time into the buffer.  I can get it to call my implementation of the virtual function overflow(int c) if I leave my buffer with no space and thereby get the data for the float and the int.

Now here is the problem, I need to know when the float is done being put into the buffer.  Or to put it another way, I need to know when this is the last time overflow will be called for a particular value being streamed in.  The reason xsputn works for me is because I get the whole value up front and its length.  So i can copy it into the buffer then call out to the function waiting for the buffer to be full.

I am admittedly abusing the ostream design in that I need to cache the output then send it all at once for each inputted value (<<).

Anyways to be clear I will restate what I am shooting for in another way.  There is a very good chance I am just going about it the wrong way.

I want to use an inherited ostream and streambuf so I can input values into it and allow it to handle my type conversion for me, then I want to ferry that information off to another object that I am passing a handle down to the streambuf to (for?).  That object has expensive i/o so I dont want to send the data 1 char at a time.

Sorry in advance if this is unclear.  And thank you for your time.

Comment: Part of the problem with this design is the assumption that you can identify individual values being streamed. When you have `std::complex<T>::operator<<(ostream& os)`, it must call `os << real << imag`. Now what is _the_ value? Logically the complex number is a single value, but `<iostream>` treats it as 2.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's not too clear what you're doing, although it sounds roughly
right.  Just to be sure: all your `ostream` does is provide
convenience constructors to create and install your `streambuf`,
a destructor, and possibly an implementation of `rdbuf` to
handle buffers of the right type.  Supposing that's true:
defining `xsputn` in your `streambuf` is purely an optimization.
The key function you have to define is `overflow`.  The simplest
implementation of `overflow` just takes a single character, and
outputs it to the sink.  Everything beyond that is optimization:
you can, for example, set up a buffer using `setp`; if you do
this, then `overflow` will only be called when the buffer is
full, or a flush was requested.  In this case, you'll have to
output buffer as well (use `pbase` and `pptr` to get the
addresses).  (The `streambuf` base class initializes the
pointers to create a 0 length buffer, so `overflow` will be
called for every character.)  Other functions which you might
want to override in (very) specific cases:

`imbue`: If you need the locale for some reason.  (Remember that
the current character encoding is part of the locale.)

`setbuf`: To allow client code to specify a buffer.  (IMHO, it's
usually not worth the bother, but you may have special
requirements.)

`seekoff`: Support for seeking.  I've never used this in any of
my `streambuf`s, so I can't give any information beyond what
you could read in the standard.

`sync`:  Called on flush, should output any characters in the
buffer to the sink.  If you never call `setp` (so there's no
buffer), you're always in sync, and this can be a no-op.
`overflow` or `uflow` can call this one, or both can call some
separate function.  (About the only difference between `sync`
and `uflow` is that `uflow` will only be called if there is
a buffer, and it will never be called if the buffer is empty.
`sync` will be called if the client code flushes the stream.)

When writing my own streams, unless performance dictates
otherwise, I'll keep it simple, and only override `overflow`.
If performance dictates a buffer, I'll usually put the code to
flush the buffer into a separate `write(address, length)`
function, and implement `overflow` and `sync` along the lines
of:

```
int MyStreambuf::overflow( int ch )
{
    if ( pbase() == NULL ) {
        // save one char for next overflow:
        setp( buffer, buffer + bufferSize - 1 );
        if ( ch != EOF ) {
            ch = sputc( ch );
        } else {
            ch = 0;
        }
    } else {
        char* end = pptr();
        if ( ch != EOF ) {
            *end ++ = ch;
        }
        if ( write( pbase(), end - pbase() ) == failed ) {
            ch = EOF;
        } else if ( ch == EOF ) {
            ch = 0;
        }
        setp( buffer, buffer + bufferSize - 1 );
    }
    return ch;
}

int sync()
{
    return (pptr() == pbase()
            || write( pbase(), pptr() - pbase() ) != failed)
        ? 0
        : -1;
}
```

Generally, I'll not bother with `xsputn`, but if your client
code is outputting a lot of long strings, it could be useful.
Something like this should do the trick:

```
streamsize xsputn(char const* p, streamsize n)
{
    streamsize results = 0;
    if ( pptr() == pbase()
            || write( pbase(), pptr() - pbase() ) != failed ) {
        if ( write(p, n) != failed ) {
            results = n;
        }
    }
    setp( buffer, buffer + bufferSize - 1 );
    return results;
}
```

Comment: That is basically what I am doing now, what I want to know is if there is anyway to tell how many times overflow is going to be called, or when the last char is coming past. For Example if I do mystream << 1.3f;  I will get the characters '1' then '.' then '3' but inside the streabuf I have no way of knowing how many characters to expect.  And after I get the 3 I want to act on the buffer (call out to another object letting it know it is ready)

Comment: There's no way the code can know in advance what the client code is going to do, or how many times it is going to be called.  What you can do is set `unitbuf` on the `ostream`: this will cause `sync` to be called at the end of every `operator<<` (in the destructor of the `sentry` object).  You then act on the buffer in `sync`.

Comment: aha! that is EXACTLY what i needed! Marking this as the answer, cant up vote it yet though, I will come back and do so once I get enough rep.  Thank you so much.

Comment: I think the sync function is problematic. It should also reset "pptr()". Take libstdc++ as an example https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/b22cf5f0321f6425a357c06647a4366d99ddac61/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/fstream.tcc#L1006C1-L1021C6. It should call `overflow` instead of `write`.